# DSH (dancer's shell) hangs when getting tail -f logs

Tags: linux, shell, logging, ssh, rhel

I'm using dancer's shell dsh (http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en) to send a tail -f command to 6 machines.  I was hoping to use this to view a merged log from a service which resides in the same directory on each of these machines.  The machines are all running RHEL 4. (Not my choice.)

What actually happens, is that I retrieve 4-20 lines from each log and then it just hangs.

Here are my options:

dsh -c -M -r ssh -g services --  /usr/bin/tail -f /var/myservice/my.log

"services" refers to a group of 6 servers.

I've tried several different ssh options in the dsh.conf file, including -n, -t, and -f, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Also, screen is not installed on the target servers.

What's wrong with my command?  How can I make it act like a proper tail -f?

Comment: Are you sure there is more output to be read from each log at this time? The purpose of the `-f` option is to wait for more output once the end of the file is reached; it sounds like `tail -f` is behaving as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out chepner's comment is right.  Those logs just don't create much output.  I tried the identical command with a set of more active web applications and it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

I know that command as "distributed shell", but no matter.

I'm suspicious the double-dash in the middle of your command string is asking for it to accept stdin input, which indeed would make it appear to hang. Try it without the "--"

Comment: `--` simply allows `-f` to be passed as-is to the remote command, rather than be mistaken for an option to `dsh`.

Comment: -- is clearly given as a way to set off the command to be run in the dsh man page.  Although dsh is referred to both as dancer's shell and distributed shell by the author, I found I could search for it more effectively by using dancer's shell.  Searching on distributed shell can lead to different implementations with entirely different command line options.